# Tablet text input

Tags: text, input

I'm installing v.14.10 on a tablet but haven't been able to locate or access an onscreen keyboard. Is one available in Ubuntu?

Comment: @ByteCommander That seems to be the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called *onboard*. I am not sure if that is a different one, but when you click on the accessibility button in the top bar (blue circle with a white stickman), you should also see a menu entry for showing an on-screen keyboard.

Some images to clarify the answer:

[image: accessibility button] [image: accessibility menu]
<sub>Accessibility button **^** . . . . . . . . . . **^** Accessibility menu</sub>

<sub>`onboard` on-screen keyboard window . . . **v**</sub>

[image: onboard on-screen keyboard window]